# Calculate height of div with dynamic content for transform animation

Tags: css, angular

I have a container with a fixed start height that only covers the `<ul>` container (see HTML/JS). If a button/link is pushed this container should expand by adding a class to the `container` div, and expand to fit the content of the entire container. This can be achieved by using the property `height: auto`, however, if I want a transition effect, e.g. `transition: height 0.2s ease-in` the `auto` property doesn't work. And it should be noted, that the content below the `<ul>` is dynamic. So it can be much more than what is seen here. So how can I get the height of the container, and input this into the `is-active` CSS class (I am using Angular)?

HTML/JS:

```
<div [ngClass]="toggleState ? 'container is-active' : 'container'">

    <ul>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="toggleState = !toggleState">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="extra-dynamic-content">Lorem ipsum</div>        

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 100px
}

.container .is-active {
    height: 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Viewchild annotation you can get the elementRef of your page, and with the elementRef you can access to the properties in the DOM.

BUT you cannot change the scss / css file of the template, this file is statically compiled. So if you want to change the style of element use ngStyle (or style directly with interpolation).